# Problem to add-migration using Package Manager Console

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am facing the following issue regarding add-migration using Package Manager Console:

```
PM> add-migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: AccountContracts
add-migration : Exception calling "GetProjectOfUniqueName" with "2" argument(s): "Exception calling "InvokeMethod" with "3" argument(s): "Object must implement IConvertible.""
At line:1 char:1
+ add-migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException,Add-Migration
```

It's working fine, but why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but not the reason.
For some reason when I created a solution folder, the project kind of lost the references, I don't know why.

The solution was, remove the solution folders, put all projects in the same folder level.

Restart the visual studio, open the Package Manage Console.

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the proper packages into the EntityFramework project and in the main one (e.g. the web or console main application) by using Nuget:

1. install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` into your EFcore project
2. install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` into the main app (e.g. your web application)
3. Restart Visual Studio (not sure this step is required)

Then, `add-migration` and all other ef-related commands works properly